# Undefined array key 0 error when checking if an array is empty

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application some of the users can have a assigned company and some don't have a assigned company.

But both type of users can update their details to the system.

If it is a user who has a company, then I'm checking his company id is a valid one or not.

If the user doesn't have an assigned company, I don't need to check that..

In order to do that I have following in my controller,

```
$companies = $user->companies;
```

This `$companies` will basically contains an collection like below,

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2770
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Company {#2778
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "companies"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:25 [
        "id" => 635
        "uuid" => "283c18b514"
        "name" => "apple"
        "email" => "ceo@apple.co"
        "phone_number" => "6149297830"
        "website" => "https://www.apple.co"
        "country_id" => 232
        "state" => "California"
        "postal_code" => ""
        "house_number" => ""
        "street" => ""
        "city" => "Menlo Park"
        "chamber_of_commerce" => null
        "vat_number" => null
        "lat" => 37.4529598
        ....
```

Now I'm trying run some codes if this **$companies is NOT empty.** which means, the user has already assigned company.

```
if(!empty($companies)){
            $getAuthUser_CompanyId = $companies[0]->id;

            $employeeID_ExistsCompany= CompanyUser::whereExists(function ($query) use ($getAuthUser_CompanyId,$employee_Id) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('users')
                    ->where('company_user.user_id', '=',$employee_Id)
                    ->where('company_id', '=', $getAuthUser_CompanyId);
            })
            ->get();

            if(!$employeeID_ExistsCompany)
            abort(403);
        }
```

**Now the issue is,**

When I try to run this It kept giving me an error saying,

> message: "Undefined array key 0"

How can I properly check if this `$companies` not empty? Where should I fix?

**Update**

Tried using

```
if($companies->isNotEmpty())
```

Since am using laravel 9, but still getting the same exception...

```
if($companies->isNotEmpty())
        {
            $getAuthUser_CompanyId = $companies->first()->id;

            $employeeID_ExistsCompany= CompanyUser::whereExists(function ($query) use ($getAuthUser_CompanyId,$employee_Id) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('users')
                    ->where('company_user.user_id', '=',$employee_Id)
                    ->where('company_id', '=', $getAuthUser_CompanyId);
            })
            ->get();

            if(!$employeeID_ExistsCompany)
            abort(403);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use count() of the collection class.

```
if($companies->count() > 0)
```

Use below code, when the relation is one-to-one

```
if($companies)
```

Comment: Not working, the same error occurring...

Comment: can you provide the  relation  code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-isnotempty

```
$companies = $user->companies;

 if($companies->isNotEmpty()){ // check if records exists

  $getAuthUser_CompanyId = $companies->first()->id; // also update this line 

   //Logic
 }
```

Comment: This is not working, still giving the same error for the users who does not have a company

Comment: are you getting the same error?

Comment: yes, message: "Undefined array key 0" even cleared laravel cache

Comment: have you update this line `$getAuthUser_CompanyId = $companies[0]->id;` ?

Comment: yes, I have updated that as well...

Comment: Please help Stack Overflow curate better content by closing new duplicate questions and only posting good unique advice on earlier questions.

Answer (score 0):

That is because a Collection is not an array.

getAuthUser_CompanyId = $companies->first()->id;